# prove that $0.2(x-1)^5$ and $4x-6$ intersect each other exactly 3 times

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Prove that $q(x) = 4x-6$ and $p(x) = 0.2(x-1)^5$ intersect each other exactly 3 times.

First we need that $p=q$.

Let $E(x) = 0.2(x-1)^5 - 4x + 6$.

$E(-2) <0, \quad E(1) > 0, \quad E(2) < 0, \quad E(3)>0$.

$E(x)$ is continuous for all $x$ therefore by Intermediate Value theorem there must be at least three $x$ such that $E(x) = 0$.

$E(x)$ is also differentiable for all $x$. By Rolle theorem if there were 4 or more roots to $E(x)$ then $E'(x)$ should have at least 3 roots.

$E'(x) = (x-1)^4 - 4$.

The only time $E'(x)=0$ is when $(x-1)^4 - 4 = 0$

$(x-1)^4 = 4$

$\sqrt[4]{(x-1)^4} = \sqrt[4]4$

$x-1=\sqrt[4]4$

$x = \sqrt[4]4 + 1$

Therefore $E'(x)$ has only one root $\Rightarrow E(x)$ has only 3 roots $\Rightarrow p$ intersects $q$ only three times.

Please let me know if my solution is correct, specifically the part with solving $(x-1)^4 = 4$.

Comment: Aren't both $1+\sqrt{2}$ and $1-\sqrt{2}$ roots of $E'(x) = 0$?

Comment: You're right! I knew I missed something. But then still we have two roots to $E'(x)$ which is less than three which still proves the point right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof on the whole seems fine. The only issue I see is that you conclude there is only $1$ root of the derivative whereas there are actually 2, namely:

$$
x = 1 \pm \sqrt 2
$$

Int there are still less than 3 roots, your proof is still valid; it is just a tiny detail you missed. Other than that your proof seems sound.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the function $\sqrt[4]{\cdot}$ only on $\mathbb{R}^+$, which explains where is hidden the missing root. The correct computation of the roots of $E'$ would be
\begin{align*}E'(x)=0\iff (x-1)^4=4&\iff (x-1)^2=2\text{ (here I can apply $\sqrt{\cdot}$ since $(x-1)^2\in\mathbb{R}^+$)}\\
&\iff x\in\{1-\sqrt{2},1+\sqrt2\}.\end{align*}
Then your conclusion is right.